# Parsing a single JSON number or string in PLSQL?

Tags: json, parsing, plsql

Is there a way to deserialize a simple JSON scalar value (e.g. *string* or *number*) in PLSQL ?

```sql
DECLARE
  j JSON_ELEMENT_T;
BEGIN
  j := JSON_ELEMENT_T.parse('5');  -- This line throws a 06512 error
END;
```

Deserializing a JSON object or a JSON array will pass, but not a simple JSON value.
I also tried *JSON_SCALAR_T.parse* with no success.

Any idea ?